# How to run Orange from the source code?

Tags: python, orange, programming

I'd like to contribute to Orange. To get used to the code, I tried to run the source code directly under Windows 10, so far without success. I have numpy and scipy installed, and the source code for orange3 from GitHub. If I run "python -m Orange.canvas" in the orange3 directory, I get the following error stack:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
__import__(pkg_name)
File "C:\Users\Timo\Documents\Eclipse\workspace\Orange Github\orange3\Orange\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .misc.lazy_module import _LazyModule
File "C:\Users\Timo\Documents\Eclipse\workspace\Orange Github\orange3\Orange\misc\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from .distmatrix import DistMatrix
File "C:\Users\Timo\Documents\Eclipse\workspace\Orange Github\orange3\Orange\misc\distmatrix.py", line 3, in <module>
from Orange.data import Table, StringVariable, Domain
File "C:\Users\Timo\Documents\Eclipse\workspace\Orange Github\orange3\Orange\data\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from .variable import *
File "C:\Users\Timo\Documents\Eclipse\workspace\Orange Github\orange3\Orange\data\variable.py", line 12, in <module>
from Orange.util import Registry, color_to_hex, hex_to_color, Reprable
File "C:\Users\Timo\Documents\Eclipse\workspace\Orange Github\orange3\Orange\util.py", line 17, in <module>
from Orange.data.util import scale  # pylint: disable=unused-import
File "C:\Users\Timo\Documents\Eclipse\workspace\Orange Github\orange3\Orange\data\util.py", line 5, in <module>
import bottleneck as bn
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bottleneck'
```

Does anyone has experience with trying to run Orange directly from the source code? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: These sorts of questions are more suited for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)